# Experience & Level Table

Tags: c#, storage, calculator

I'm working on a small self learning project with an EXP/Level calculator for a game and I just need a little advice.

I'm wondering what would be the best storage method to store a Level (1, 2, 3 up to 110) and an experience requirement for that level. I would like to be able to search for the level by an exp value, for example if level 9 is 1000 XP, and level 10 is 2,000 XP I'd be able to search for level 9 by inputting an XP value of 1000 - 1999.

So far I've researched SQL/List/Dictionary/Arrays and all seem good, but I can't find something that performs the operation I described.

Comment: If you found something that is good (meaning it works for your case) - use it. If you later find that something is not good enough with taken approach you'll have much better information to ask more concrete question than this.

Comment: `var exp = new Dictionary<int, int> {{9, 1000}, {10, 2000}}; var level = exp.Where(y => y.Value <= yourXPToCheck).Max(x => x.Key);`

Comment: Most games experience calculations come from a mathematical formula, so you shouldnt need an array at all, just figure out the formula where you can substitue **x** for the level required. Otherwise I'm guessing your just going to be taking this from a text file or similar so just extract that to an array of (numberformat) where the level will be the index of that item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of levels is only up to 110, you could just keep the ranges in an ordered list or array like so:

```
   0
 100
 200
 400
 600
 800
1000
1300
1600
```

and so on (I made up those numbers of course!)

Then you could search for the level for a particular XP value by either linearly searching the list (which would be fast enough probably) or if you really needed to you could use [`Array.BinarySearch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx) to find the nearest level, and do a check of the values to either side to see which band the XP falls into.

The level will just be the index of the found band + 1 (since levels start at 1, not 0).

To linearly search for the level for an XP value:

```
int[] xpArray = new [] { 0, 100, ... etc }// The list as shown above
int targetXP = 850;
int level = 0;

while ((level < xpArray.Length) && (targetXP > xpArray[level]))
    ++level;

// Now you have the right level.
```

Obviously this is just a brief overview to get you started! Also, you might need to adjust things slightly; I don't know your exact requirements. Does a character with 0 XP have level 0, for example?

The key thing to take away from this is the concept of searching a list of numbers, and using the index of the band that you find as a basis for the level, and also the fact that you only need to store one number for each band. You don't need to store a min and max value for each band, nor do you need to store the level. Those values are implicit.

I leave using `Array.BinarySearch()` to speed things up as an excercise for the reader... ;)